# Jquery: run code when text is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML document which llokes like this:

```
<div class="this_can_be_selected">Some text here</div>
<div>No text in the div above is selected</div>

<div class="this_can_be_selected">Some text here</div>
<div>No text in the div above is selected</div>

<div class="this_can_be_selected">Some text here</div>
<div>No text in the div above is selected</div>
```

I want text `No text in the div above is selected` to be changed to `Some text in the div above is selected` when, guess what, some of the text in the div above is selected :)

jQuery has a [.select() event](http://api.jquery.com/select/), that would make this rather easy to do, but seems, that it works when selected text is inside input or textarea.

Here is a code that I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {

        //Some text inside div is selected
        $('DIV.this_can_be_selected').select
        (
            function()
            {
                alert('Something is selected!');
                $(this).next().html('Some text in the div above is selected');
            }
        );

    }
);
```

Nothing is happening.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery core doesn't have anything for this, but there are [some plugin options](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/textselect).

Your code would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).bind('textselect', function(e) {
    alert('Selected Text: ' + e.text);
  });    
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HkZKX/).